# asp.net mvc bind to telerik grid without model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-mvc

Is it possible to bind an object collection to telerik mvc control without defining the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly you mean without model?

If you are talking about the model which is defined for view - strongly typed view then yes it is possible to bind it. You need to specify the type of the model like this `Html.Telerik().Grid<YourType>((IEnumerable<YourType>)Model)`

If you are talking about omitting the Grid type declared here - then you can specify **dinamic** type there and use the approach covered in this code library to successfully bind the grid.
http://www.telerik.com/community/code-library/aspnet-mvc/grid/binding-to-a-collection-of-dynamic-objects-with-mvc3-razor.aspx

I hope this is what you search for.